# React native transparent search bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I adjust my search bar to have an transparent background?
What's the transparent color tag for the

I like the dark color of the search input, but I would like to get rid of the box around it?

```
import SearchBar from 'react-native-search-bar';
....

  <View>
    <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(1.0, 0, 0, 0.2)" translucent />
    <SearchBar
      ref='searchBar'
      placeholder='Search a spot'
      barTintColor="#222222"
      tintColor="white"
      textColor="white"
      textFieldBackgroundColor="#444444"
      hideBackground={true}
      barStyle="default"
      searchBarStyle="minimal"
      showsCancelButtonWhileEditing={false}
    />
    <MapView
      provider={ PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
      style={ styles.container }
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 32.815013,
        longitude: -117.273404,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      }}
    />
  </View>
```

I tried setting `barTintColor="rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);"` but that seems to not be working.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't know which prop you should use to set background color because I have never used that library but for transparent background you can use `{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }`

Answer (score 1):

If `barTintColor` is what you're referring to, add color something like this:

```
barTintColor="#2222221A"
```

Here the format is #RRGGBBAA -> AA stands for alpha in hex ranging from 00 to FF that basically lets you set opacity.

I hope this answered your question.